# Reference errors building OpenCV Android CVCamera_MSER sample app

Tags: eclipse, opencv, reference, android-ndk, cygwin

I'm relatively new to Android development, as well as OpenCV. I've tried out some OpenCV samples found with the sdk (using [OpenCV2.4.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.2/)), as well as some [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/) offered by Stanford University. The first two samples by Stanford worked fine (*histogram equalization* and *color histogram*).   However I've spent almost a week now trying to get the remaining three to run.

I've already installed Android ndk and tried a hello world android app using ndk once and the three sample projects in question seem to all need native code (thus ndk).

On selecting the project in eclipse the console reads:

```
<terminated> Native Builder CVCamera_MSER [Program] C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe

/usr/bin/bash: 1ine 0: cd: /home/Davidchen/opencv/android/apps/cvCamera_MSER: No such file or directory
```

I tried building the native project using the commands in the command line (as I understood from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)):

> ```
> cd {project path}  
> {ndk path}/ndk-build
> ```

However scores of errors appeared, all reference-related, since there are inumerable references to `home/DavidChen`. There is no folder on my computer named DavidChen. My guess is that there is a reference somewhere to the project path within the cygwin home folder of the project's author. I still cannot find where this faulty reference is specified however so that I could alter it to an existing one instead; I've looked into the *paths and symbols* under the *C/C++ General* Project Properties in eclipse as well as the source files, both native code and java code.

When I've tried it on cgywin's console, it still didn't work.

---

The errors are upon trying to run the project CVCamera_MSER, under the project video titled **Local Feature Points** found in the link provided above (also [here][14] for convenience). I've also tried running the projects *Edges, Lines, and Circles* and *Feature Tracking* with no success.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 running on Windows7 x64bit.

Thank you for your time.